# Does Barbie set rules for hairstyles for Kens in Barbie Land?

Tags: barbie-2023

After returning from the Real World to Barbie Land, Ken speaks to Barbie:

> Ken: You know, now that you Barbies aren't around to run everything,
> **we can do our hair however we like**.

Does Barbie set rules for hairstyles for Kens in Barbie Land?

Comment: Or it is possible that in Barbie land they felt they needed to cut their hair in a way that would make Barbie happy. In the real world tbere are lots of other people who like different things.

Comment: A major theme of the movie is that the way the Kens are treated is wrong and needs to change.